# How to get the content of an object after iterate on it?

Tags: python, iteration

After a 'for' loop on a  <_io.TextIOWrapper > object, I get an empty string when I try to read it again.

```
#! python3

import subprocess
import sys

cmd = ['sudo', 'apt', 'update']
p = subprocess.Popen(
    cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, text=True)
for line in p.stdout:
    sys.stdout.write(line)

print(p.stdout.read())
```

I am forced to create an array before and append to it.

```
#! python3

import subprocess
import sys

cmd = ['sudo', 'apt', 'update']
p = subprocess.Popen(
    cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, text=True)

stdout = []  # I create an array

for line in p.stdout:
    sys.stdout.write(line)
    stdout.append(line)  # And append to it

print(stdout)
```

Why does it behave like this?
Is there a better way? Something like `p.stdout.reset_object()`?

Comment: This really is the simplest way to do this.

Comment: If you run that command at a command prompt, the output goes to the console. If you want to see the output again, you have to run the program a second time. A  `subprocess` call works exactly the same. That is why it behaves that way. Your terminal program may let you copy the text off the screen after the command has run. That is because the terminal program keeps the text in a screen buffer. The array you create is an implementation of the same screen buffer concept. `subprocess` does not do this for you. There is a good reason for that: your command might not terminate until killed.

Comment: @BoarGules That's really well explained,thank youi will stay with my list i guess

Answer (score 1):

You have an iterator. Once an iterator is consumed, you cannot go back. If you want to iterate through it again, the easiest way is to create a list from it, as you did.

One thing that would be a bit nicer is to create the list in one go:

```
 stdout = list(p.stdout)
```

Then you can iterate over `stdout` as many times as you want.